# Giving access to /var/run/apache2/wsgi.xxxx.x.x.sock file

Tags: flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

my vps is running webuzo panel
i tried installing my python api using the webuzo panel realizing that cant have my way, i'm trying to setup the python api manually

if my server is just a normal ubuntu server i know the setup, but the webuzo panel changes the server, following changes

- there is a root user and normal users
- normal users can add domains and domain addons like in a cpanel
- if you create a new user in the panel, you cannot ssh to that user, only the root user can ssh
- apache2.service is httpd.service
- /etc/apache2/ is in /usr/local/apps/apache2/etc/
- if i manually edit the httpd.conf file it will reset my edits on `sudo systemctl restart httpd` commad
- i can only add an extension to a domain with a configuration file in `/usr/local/apps/apache2/etc/conf.d/api.example.com/api.example.com.conf` which will be included in the larger file automatically created by webuzo in `/usr/local/apps/apache2/etc/conf.d/webuzoVH.conf`

webuzo.conf file

```
<VirtualHost ip-address:80>     
    
    
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule suexec_module>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup user1 user1
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule ruid2_module>
        RMode config
        RUidGid user1 user1
    </IfModule>
    
    Include /usr/local/apps/apache2/etc/conf.d/api.example.com/api.example.com.conf
    ServerName api.example.com
    ServerAlias www.api.example.com mail.api.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/public_html/api.example.com
    <FilesMatch \.(php|phtml)$>
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/apps/php73/var/fpm-user1.sock|fcgi://localhost"   
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule alias_module>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/user1/public_html/api.example.com/cgi-bin/
    </IfModule>
    
    ServerAdmin user1@example.com
    <IfFile /usr/local/apps/apache2/www/noindex.html>
        Alias /error/ /usr/local/apps/apache2/www/
    </IfFile>
    
    
    # webmail access from mail.domain.com
    <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mail.api.example.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mail.api.example.com:443
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) /___webuzo_subdomain_webmail/$1 [PT]
        ProxyPass "/___webuzo_subdomain_webmail" "http://127.0.0.1:2002/mail"
    </ifModule>
    
    
    
    ErrorLog /usr/local/apps/apache2/logs/api.example.com.err
    CustomLog /usr/local/apps/apache2/logs/api.example.com.log combined
    
    IncludeOptional /var/webuzo-data/apache2/custom/users/user1.conf
    IncludeOptional /var/webuzo-data/apache2/custom/domains/api.example.com.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

api.example.com.conf file

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/apps/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-3.10

ServerName  api.example.com
ServerAlias api.example.com www.api.example.com

WSGIDaemonProcess python-api user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user1/public_html/python-api/python-flask-v2/passenger.wsgi

<Directory /home/user1/public_html/python-api/python-flask-v2>
    WSGIProcessGroup python-api
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static /home/user1/public_html/python-api/python-flask-v2/app/static
<Directory /home/user1/public_html/python-api/python-flask-v2/app/static/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /usr/local/apps/apache2/logs/api.example.com.err
CustomLog /usr/local/apps/apache2/logs/api.example.com.log combined

IncludeOptional /var/webuzo-data/apache2/custom/users/user1.conf
IncludeOptional /var/webuzo-data/apache2/custom/domains/api.example.com.conf
```

when restart the server, apache server works fine
but i get 50x error when go to http://api.example.com/
and the error log

```
[Thu Jul 06 02:16:23.108317 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 2985144] (13)Permission denied: [client 123.231.104.25:19169] mod_wsgi (pid=2985144): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'python-api' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.2985124.0.1.sock' as user with uid=1000.
[Thu Jul 06 02:16:25.023888 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 2985199] (13)Permission denied: [client 123.231.104.25:19170] mod_wsgi (pid=2985199): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'python-api' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.2985124.0.1.sock' as user with uid=1000., referer: https://api.example.com/
```

i tried checked the ownership of the directory `/var/run/apache2/` because everytime i go to http://api.example.com the `wsgi.xxxx.x.x.sock` file changes
`ps aux | grep /var/run/apache2/`
result
`root     2985245  0.0  0.0   3452  1800 pts/9    S+   01:43   0:00 grep --color=auto /var/run/apache2/`

so changed ownership to `user1`
`sudo chown user1:user1 /var/run/apache2/`
but nothing change, same error occured

changed ownership to `www-data`
`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/run/apache2/`
but nothing changed